# Access html element via ngModel

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

Imagine something like this:

```
<input type='text' ng-model="x">
```

Now, using x in the controller, how can I change this element? let's say I want to change its class. Or add a random element before it.

**Please note that I strictly wanna access the html element.**

any idea?

Answer (score -1):

Nope, editing `$scope.x` in your controller only sets the **value** of the input. If you want to change its class, use `ng-class`.

Adding a random element before it is not that simple. You would need a ng-repeat or make it a directive. See if you can find a basic angular.js tutorial. That may help.